# Change value of nested scope in Angular (have plunker)

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items that when I click populates an input with the item name. The data is nested.

**PLUNKER:** https://plnkr.co/edit/9PSkYAihxa6KRbJJcAxY?p=preview

I can't for the life of me work out how when I change the input value to have the value in the list update too.

It's taken me a while to work out how to share data, just this last step is the one that has really got me pulling my hair out.

To sum up: I would like that when the input is populated with the item name, I can change the item name using the input.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="DashboardController">

    <p>Click on a part. I would like edit the part name.</p>
    <input ng-model="partname" />
    <button ng-click="changeName();">Change selected name</button>

    <div ng-repeat="vehicle in toorder">
      <h3>Parts required for: {{vehicle.make}} {{vehicle.model}}</h3>
      <ul ng-controller="ToOrderItemControler" ng-repeat="part in vehicle.parts">
        <li ng-click="partClick(part);">{{part.part_name}} ({{part.component}}) - click me</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {

    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.partname = '';

    sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(val) {

        this.partname = val;
        this.broadcastItem();

    };

    sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return sharedService;


})

.controller('ToOrderItemControler', function($scope, mySharedService) {

    $scope.partClick = function(part) {
        mySharedService.prepForBroadcast(part.part_name);

    };

})

.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, $http, mySharedService) {

  $scope.changeName = function() {

  }

  $scope.toorder = [];

  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
      $scope.partname = mySharedService.partname;
  });      

  $scope.loadData = function () {
      var httpRequest = $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'data.json',
      }).success(function (data, status) {
          $scope.toorder = data;

      });

  };  

  $scope.loadData();

});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Will real app have same nested controller set up? if so `ToOrderItemControler` already inherits from `DashboardController` which makes this whole thing fairly simple

Comment: Yes the real app will be nested like that. The architecture has to remain the same.

Comment: Main issue you face is not storing reference to actual object. Pass object not just property of that object. Doesn't matter where you update the original object from that way because objects are passed by reference. With your approach you have no idea where the `partname` came from originally

Comment: Thanks. Your help fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to pass the entire object, not just the single value.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="DashboardController">


    <p>Click on a part. I would like edit the part name.</p>
    <input ng-model="part.part_name" />
    <button ng-click="changeName();">Change selected name</button>

    <div ng-repeat="vehicle in toorder">
      <h3>Parts required for: {{vehicle.make}} {{vehicle.model}}</h3>
      <ul ng-controller="ToOrderItemControler" ng-repeat="part in vehicle.parts">
        <li ng-click="partClick(part);">{{part.part_name}} ({{part.component}}) - click me</li>
      </ul>
    </div>



  </div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {

    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.part = {};

    sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(part) {

        this.part = part;
        this.broadcastItem();

    };

    sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return sharedService;


})

.controller('ToOrderItemControler', function($scope, mySharedService) {

    $scope.partClick = function(part) {
        mySharedService.prepForBroadcast(part);

    };

})

.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, $http, mySharedService) {

  $scope.changeName = function() {

  }

  $scope.toorder = [];

  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
      $scope.part = mySharedService.part;
  });      

  $scope.loadData = function () {
      var httpRequest = $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'data.json',
      }).success(function (data, status) {
          $scope.toorder = data;

      });

  };  

  $scope.loadData();

});
```